# How to quick move+resize a window using ALT key+Mouse on Ubuntu Mate 15.04?

Tags: desktop, mate-desktop, window-management

On earlier Linux GUI Desktops, it was quick and easy to  move around or resize any window just by holding the ALT Button + clicking and dragging the mouse on almost any position of the app window, so there was no need to "aim" for a specific "handle" or spot on the window.

With Ubuntu Mate 15.04, it seems it does not work anymore. Surprisingly, I haven't even managed to find a solution on the net yet.

Does anyone know how to re-enable this feature on the default Ubuntu Mate 15.04 Desktop ?

Comment: Does it work if you use Alt + middle click?

Comment: Negative! is not working with ALT + any mouse button combination so far :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: i dont know why or what happened since back then.. but in the meanwhile holding ALT + left click DOES WORK moving any window . and ALT+RIGHT click does resize. just as it does since gnome. - i have no idea why this happened and is now fixed. :( well, some updates happened in the meanwhile. but i donno if they fixed it or not.

so it seems it works in MATE just the same as in gnome. but somehow it wasnt working for quiet some time, while it does now as its supposed to.