# How to view parts of a window limited by screen resolution?

Tags: window-manager, window

Window manager is MATE. OS is Debian 10. In certain applications, I'm stuck with windows I can't resize. Working on laptops, screen resolution is sadly limited, so the lower parts of these unresizable windows are cut off. (I have two laptops with this issue, and my friend has a third)

How can I just move the window upwards so I can reach these parts of the window? Unfortunately MATE will not let me move the window off the screen using the alt+f7 shortcut.

Happy to use a different window manager temporarily just to get this to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quick move+resize a window using ALT key+Mouse on Ubuntu Mate 15.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230834/how-to-quick-moveresize-a-window-using-alt-keymouse-on-ubuntu-mate-15-04)

Comment: I've tried to move the window with alt+f7 but MATE won't let me move the window past the top of the screen unfortunately.

Comment: alt+left click and drag works, just tested it, thank you!